# Visual SourceSafe 2005 integrated with VS2008 - missing checkin prompt for comment

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe, prompt, checkin

I have been using Visual Studio integrated with Source Safe for years, when I checkin a file from the Solution Explorer in VS2008 I am not prompted for a comment when I previously I was prompted. To add a comment now, I go to the pending checkin view and add a comment that way. My guess at some point I must have accidentally changed some option. But I cannot seem to figure out where. I have looked in the SourceSafe Admin options, the SourceSafe user tool option and VS2008 options, but I am missing it. This is not a big deal, but I do miss the prompt. This change happened about a year ago, and every now an then, I look around a bit to try to change the behavior, but I never find the right flag to change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio select Tools -> options, expand Source Control from the tree I think the setting is in there.  But I've just had to rebuild my machine and didn't install the VSS client, so I can't check the settings.

EDIT: I have reinstalled the VSS client now.  Under the options mentioned above, if you select Environment there is some text at the bottom... "If dialogs were hidden using Don't show this again, click Reset to view them again."... press the Reset button.

Comment: It is probably staring me in the face, but I don't see it.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the source control item many times, but for some reason I never noticed the Environment selection in the tree. I am glad to finally have my prompt for checkin back.

Comment: Cheers, this prompt mysteriously dissapeared for me too!

-- Lee

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the Visual SourceSafe plugin first.

Go to Tools -> Options.
Select Source Control->Plug-in Selection in the tree.

Choose Visual SoruceSafe.
Now you should have a new item in the tree called Source Control->Environment.

In that dialog you have a couple of checkboxes that tells how VSS should prompt or not prompt.

Comment: Thanks you and David both had the answer to my question.